# MySQL datetime is 2 hours off?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a very strange problem that I can't wrap my head around... I have a PHP file which outputs this:
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())

And it outputs the correct datetime. Then I try to save this into a MySQL datetime field (using Wordpress DB API, not that it matters) - but the time recorded in the database is two hours off! For example, it will say 2011-07-09 09:00:57, when it's supposed to be 2011-07-09 11:00:57.

Is there some separate time settings for mySQL or something that could cause this to happen? Can anyone think of reasons this might happen, and I will investigate it. I don't know what to look for right now.

Comment: What time zone are you in? 99% of the time, questions like this are the difference between your local time zone and UTC.

Comment: Are u running your server in different timezone

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log in your wp admin. then goto  [Settings > General](http://en.support.wordpress.com/settings/general-settings/).Then you can change Timezone settings

Comment: This is very likely my problem. Nothing happens when I change it though :/

Comment: Alright, I still don't know why nothing happens when I change the time zone in the admin area. But I solved it by putting date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm'); in functions.php. I am going to mark this answer as being correct because you realized it was due to WP's timezone settings and because that way people will be able to know about how I solved this, ugly as it may be.

Comment: @calle: I have that answer, But I never used that. so i hesitate to suggest.Anyway thanks

Answer (score 6):

You probably need to set the proper [timezone](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) in your MySQL server or your connection to that server.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set the server time for mysql. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html